# System.ArgumentNullException : 'La valeur ne peut pas être null. Nom du paramètre : part

Tags: html, vb.net, docx

I have a problem with the code and more specifically with this line:

```
Dim htmlX As XElement = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(wDoc:=doc, htmlConverterSettings:=settings)
```

Every time I get the error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: La valeur ne peut pas être null.
> Nom du paramètre : part

Code:

```
Public Sub ConvertToHtml()

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("Claude La Colombière.docx")

        Using memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            memoryStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)

            Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, True)
                Dim settings As HtmlConverterSettings = New HtmlConverterSettings() With {
                    .PageTitle = "Prénommer"
                }
                Dim htmlX As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = HtmlConverter.ConvertToHtml(wDoc:=doc, htmlConverterSettings:=settings)

                File.WriteAllText("Claude La Colombière.html", htmlX.ToStringNewLineOnAttributes()) 
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub
```

I can't find any solution. What can I try next?

Comment: You should look at the [`StackTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-5.0) of the Exception, that will tell you *where* the exception is being thrown.

Comment: How is a StackTrace carried out? Thank you.

Comment: I provided a link in my previous comment, I recommend you read through it. Understanding what a [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.stacktrace?view=net-5.0) is is important IMO.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thanks Igor. I managed to intercept the StackTrace message by deploying a Try / Catch. It will serve me a lot.